# How to configure an Android emulator for the Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, kindle-fire, hdpi

I want to configure an emulator to be compatible with the Kindle Fire, including its resolution.  What do I have to change in the emulator settings (or elsewhere)?

Comment: You shouldn't rely solely on emulator when testing your application, since it lacks many hardware features. It's highly recomended to test your app on real device.

Comment: Obviously it would be nice to test all of our apps on every piece of Android hardware available, but it's a ridiculous idea.

Comment: This blog gives you some detail on how to set the DPI for different devices on the emulator: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/emulator-settings-for-each-android-density/ My Blog :-D

Comment: There is already a specific Kindle Fire emulator that comes with API 10 (which I think is 2.3.3).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Amazon Kindle Fire FAQ](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire):

> You should configure your emulator with the following characteristics:
>
> - **Width**: 600px
> - **Height**: 1024px
> - **Abstracted LCD Density**: 169
> - **Target**: Android 2.3.4 - API Level 10
> - **RAM**: 512 MB
>
> *Note: The device will reserve 20px to display a soft key menu, making the effective portrait resolution 1004px high x 600px wide and the effective landscape resolution 580px high x 1024px wide.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon recently released a new kindle fire add-on that you can easily install. It emulates the look and feel of the devices and can be set up in eclipse or from the command line. Check the documentation here for how to install and run it:

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/emulator-guide.html

Also because the kindle fire uses API level 10 it will not use your resource folders that use the swdp qualifier, so I have found using the -large-mdpi suffix for your relevant resource folders works well.

Comment: The link redirects to the generic "Tools" page, and the original AVD guide is nowhere to be found. Looks like Amazon has discontinued it.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev even if my answer is outdated, I hope, it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24285802/957954

Answer (score 3):

When creating or editing an AVD, you can select Skin: *Built-in* (and then choose some predefined screen type) or *Resolution* - that's where you can set any custom resolution. Is that what you need?

Comment: I have done like that. I have create galaxy tab with the resolution of 1024X600 so will it be works for the Amazon Kindle fire  ?

Comment: You may also want to check the supported features in the FAQ and set the emulator hardware properties accordingly. E.g., disable the camera, etc. https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire

Comment: @Shrey Sorry, I don't quite clearly understood, what do you mean. You do not create "Galaxy Tab" or "Kindle Fire". It just a virtual device with some characteristics like target system version, resolution, memory size, hardware features and so on. So what do you mean by "will it be works for the Amazon Kindle fire"?

Comment: I mean i have made one application. But it dosent seen well in Amazon Kindle fire. So i want to make the suitable layout for such resolution. Thus i am talking about to make the emulator which is same in resolution of the Amazon Kindle fire. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Well, if you want to test on AVD with the same resolution (1024x600 for example), then create one and select in configuration window **Skin: Resolution:** and set appropriate values - 1024x600. Of course emulator could not substitute a real device. For example, it shows its virtual screen on your real display with a different density and phisical size will also differ. You can partially improve it: when starting an AVD select **Scale display to real size** and set screen size of the emulated device as well as screen density (in dpi) of your monitor.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Amazon Kindle Fire Emulator just became available. Check it out at https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment</strike>

It relies on Android SDK, of course.

Update: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-set-up-your-development-environment.html

> As of Fire OS 5, the previously available Fire Tablet SDK add-on is deprecated; however, you can still develop apps for Fire tablets. Use the Android API 22 (Lollipop) features and the  Amazon Mobile Apps SDK for your apps.

Comment: @Maxgmer done, but there's no longer an emulator, just the default android stuff should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

***Note:** The device will reserve 20px to display a soft key menu, making the effective portrait resolution 1004px high x 600px wide and the effective landscape resolution 580px high x 1024px wide.

Be aware that this is true in FULL SCREEN mode only (i.e. hidden status bar). If you don't use FULL SCREEN mode that the available space is descreased by 25px on the top of the screen and about 50px (approximately) at the bottom of the screen.