# Kindle Fire Emulator no longer supported

Tags: android

Given that Amazon no longer support Android emulators for Kindle Fire (confirmed to me in an email from them), how does anyone work out if all functionality of an app (eg reverse Geocoding) released to the Amazon app store is working correctly without buying one ?

Also is there a way to see that Admob is working correctly on Amazon devices ?

Answer (score 10):

Concentrated_Attitude, there is no way to install Kindle Fire emulators from their addons.xml

If someone needs them, I have three emulators, but only for [Gen3 devices](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ams-7acUnjynaQP7NgoRL9crX3g). 
Уou need to extract this files into the Android SDK folder, using the following hierarchy:

- android_sdk:

  - extras
  - addons

    - addon_kindle_xxx

[Get all files](http://1drv.ms/1r6FASe)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been looking for those for a while, and didn't get any feedback from Amazon reps on restoring access to them in the add-ons (even without particular further support or updates).

Comment: Err, it doesn't even support the silk browser. What a joke!

Comment: @hexalys This is the simplest how you can [enable internet](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/simulate-a-cellular-network-over-wi-fi-using-androids-emulator/) on your emulator.

Comment: Better to post steps here on SO that will be forever and helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Support for the Kindle Fire emulator seems to have been discontinued as of sometime in early 2014. You can still find the page describing it here on the Wayback Machine, but now it is gone from the Amazon developer pages:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130919204543/https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/emulator-guide.html

On this forum page:

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=479

an Amazon developer rep finally states that "We have dropped supporting Emulator. Sorry for the inconvenience."

The Amazon developer site's "Pre-Submission Assessment" page says to use an actual Kindle Fire device for testing:

"To complete this group of tests, install the app on a Kindle Fire tablet and launch."

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/03-pre-submission-assessment-guide

They don't actually say "we had an emulator, but it didn't work out," but as we've been left to draw our own conclusions, that might be a pretty good summation.

For its new Fire phone, Amazon has made available a testing service which uses an actual time-shared Fire phone to which your APK gets uploaded. The test routine will push some buttons and make some random pokes at grids and the like, and some random keyboard entries, and then a few minutes to hours later you'll get a link to the results (including actions performed and their relative times of occurrence, and the resulting screen shots, plus a logcat) on your developer account. It works but it is by no means a comprehensive test.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/app-testing-service

For my part, I have just purchased a Kindle Fire HD 2013 solely for testing, used, with a tiny crack in the corner of the display but otherwise working fine, for a very low price. It's always better to have a real device than an emulator anyway.

I'll probably supplement that with some regular AVDs that are as close as possible to the various other Kindle Fire devices.

Answer (score 1):

For that you should Download the Amazon plug-in in your Eclipse and download the amazon SDK after it will provide you the amazon kindle fire emulators of all versions.
you can check and implement your all functionality in it.
you can get more [REFRENCE_HERE](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/android/)

Comment: I have a recent email from Amazon Mobile App Distribution Support Team
that says "In regard to the Kindle Fire Emulators, we no longer support emulators for Kindle Fire." I think this may be a fairly recent development.